# Agrupamento de tabela groupby pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

**Eu tenho uma tabela nesse formato**

```
User   Material   Nota
1       youtube    5
2       facebook   4
3       facebook   3
4       facebook   5
6       youtube    2
7       orkut      3
8       twitter    4
```

**e gostaria de agrupar de forma que na tabela final mostra apenas sites
avaliados por mais de 1 usuario diferente**

```
Material   User    Nota
youtube     1      5
            6      2
facebook    2      4 
            3      3
            4      5
```

meu código e minha lógica

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("tabela1.csv",delimiter=",")


tabela2= pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby(["Material","User","Nota"]).size()})


del tabela2['count']

tabela2.to_csv('tabela_2.csv')
tabela2 = pd.read_csv("tabela_2.csv",delimiter=",")
```

porém assim ele lista as que foram avaliadas por 1 usuario, gostaria de saber se existe algo no grupby que lista apenas os diferentes para agrupar?

**O que eu pensei fazer os dois for's sento 1 fixo na coluna de Material e no caso contando quantas vezes cada material aparece  depois deletar os materiais que aparecem menos q duas vezes, para tratar materiais com menos de 1 avaliação, porém eu acredito que para uma base muito grande isso vai ficar muito custoso no tempo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `value_counts` pra descobrir quais dos valores da coluna `Material` têm mais de uma entrada, e depois filtrar seu DataFrame por esses valores:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

dados = io.StringIO("""
User,Material,Nota
1,youtube,5
2,facebook,4
3,facebook,3
4,facebook,5
6,youtube,2
7,orkut,3
8,twitter,4""")

df = pd.read_csv(dados, index_col='User')

# Criamos uma série com a contagem de 
# ocorrências pra cada valor da coluna Material
counts = df['Material'].value_counts()
print(counts)  # facebook 3, youtube 2, orkut 1...

# Filtramos para que a série só inclua os 
# materiais com mais de uma contagem
counts = counts[counts > 1]
print(counts.index)  # Index(['facebook', 'youtube'], dtype='object')

# Filtramos o dataframe original para que 
# contenha somente entradas que estejam na série
df = df[df['Material'].isin(counts.index)]
print(df)

# Se quisermos, podemos ordená-los também, como
# no exemplo dado na questão
df = df.sort_values('Material')
print(df)
```

Resultado final:

```
User  Material     Nota
2     facebook     4
3     facebook     3
4     facebook     5
1      youtube     5
6      youtube     2
```